# I accidentally wrote "pip3 install f" and it installed something

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I pressed `pip3 install f` accidentally and it installed some modules i think. How do i uninstall this module that I got? It would be useful to learn how to uninstall pip3 installed modules in general

```
pip3 install f
Collecting f
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/8c/cbf1a85c4bc899bf64f3b32626056aaa8ded20e66df4396d13f82059ed39/f-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Six (from f)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: Six, f
Successfully installed Six-1.11.0 f-0.0.1
```

Comment: `pip3 uninstall Six f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip3 uninstall Six f
```

Its pretty straightforward.